# Store class name of clicked class as variable and pass it to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm fairly new to javascript. Below is my javascript code. There are many clickable-classes having some `id` Eg:

```
<a href="#" id="15" class="firefly-button lfloat"><div class="contentBoxes captionfull">
```

If a user clicks on it, I want to store a variable as `"showf15"`.   `["show"+first-character of clicked-class+id]`

To achieve this, I wrote the following line:

```
c = "show"+$(this).charAt(0)+this.id;
```

My jvascript code is:

```
$(function () {
        $(".primavera-button, .lectures-button, .firefly-button, .argentum-button, .workshops-button, .exhibitions-button").click(function (e) {
            c = "show"+$(this).charAt(0)+this.id;
                e.stopPropagation();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../fetchevents.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    id: c
                },
                ....
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

If, I'm able to achieve the variable `c` as `showl15` etc., my database table contains textual data having the `c`=id, which I can retrieve as result in json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` isn't the name of the class but the jQuery wrapped element.

Use

```
"show"+this.className[0]+this.id;
```

Comment: @xan: Some old browsers don't support `[]` on strings, so if you need to support them, stick with `.charAt(0)` instead of `[0]`. So basically, change `$(this)` to `this.className`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. By the way, I was being looking for the compatibility table of strings seen as array and I didn't found it. Do you know what are those old browsers and how old ?

Comment: @ dystroy: I don't have a good reference for it, no. I know that it doesn't work on IE7 and below, or in IE8 in "compatibility" mode, so that could well remain relevant. It works in IE8 standards mode and above. It's worked for a very long time in Firefox. I suspect it's probably worked forever in Chrome, as Chrome came later to the party. :-) (You can try it here if you want to try more of them: http://jsbin.com/elazif/1 )